# Google Maps Places not working on Android

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to develop a web page that uses the Google Maps API. So, I'm using this library: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places

The page loads fine in a `UIWebView` on iOS: the lat/long coordinates get set correctly and I can create custom markers based on the maps search query that I run.

The same code does not run in a `WebView` on Android. The map doesn't center around the lat/long coordinates. It just shows a map. I can interact with the map (scroll, zoom, etc.), but it didn't ask for permission to use my current location the way it did on iOS.

Is there something I need to set in my test app's manifest or in the WebView's settings to get this to work on Android? I have already enabled JavaScript on the WebView. I assumed that the JavaScript Google Maps API would work in an iOS web view and an Android web view.

Note that I am not asking about a native solution for this problem. That is, I don't want to kick it to the Google Maps Android app, and I certainly cannot use a `MapView` because all I actually have control over is the web page. My webpage is getting loaded into webviews on iOS and Android, and I am just testing using a simple Android app whose only Activity has a WebView in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Maps in Android is easier than you think.
This is a very good tutorial about using it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start . 
The only "pain" is get your API Key but will be very easy after that. 
This is a part of the code that "zooms" your marked position:

```
LatLng posLL = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posLL).title("Eu!"));
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posLL, 10);
mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Regards,

Marcello